# Сборка Qt4.8.7 из исходников, linux

Tags: qt, build

Для старого софта требуется QT4.8.7. При сборке из иходников получаю:

> qprintdialog_unix.cpp:281:19: error: ‘class Ui::QPrintPropertiesWidget’ has no member named ‘cupsPropertiesPage’

Аналогичных ошибок много, но они повторяющиеся. Гуглеж ничего не дал. Кто виноват - я знаю. А вот что делать - нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Comment: Под какую ОС собираете? Сборка из архива с сайта Qt не подойдет?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже Вы хотите собрать из исходников Вашего дитрибутива и смешались заголовочные файлы системной Qt и архива. Удалите -dev пакеты связанные с Qt. Установите зависимости через `apt build-dep qt4-x11`, для этого должны быть включенны deb-src репозитории от `bionic` или `buster`

Инструкция тут https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/install-x11.html
Архив с исходниками тут https://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/

Хотя я рекомендую установить Debian Buster вместо сборки - современный дистрибутив, но qt4 ещё не выпиленна.

Comment: Собиираю из тарболла архива Qt, в отдельной директории. Ранее собирал 5.X - без проблем.

Comment: Посмотри какие параметры `-I` у компилятора получаются. Похоже инклудит кут другой версии..

Comment: (https://pastebin.com/XRLNWH1f) - часть лога, пути все, вроде, в пределах одной диркетории

Comment: @Boris часть через usr local, часть через .. - это одна и та же папка?

Comment: из /usr берутся glib, freetype, остальные берутся по относительным путям из директории, где находтся исходники и билд-директория.